# What should I do with mold on my scoby?

Tags: vinegar

I'm making vinegar by adding all natural apple juice to all natural apple cider vinegar with mother.

A scoby formed on top.

Mold is now growing on top of the scoby.  It's stuck on top of the scoby, not floating on top.  I can't​ easily scrape it off without scraping the scoby.

Should I leave this mold on top, will it affect the vinegar?

Comment: This page on kombucha scoby *might* be of interest: http://www.kombuchabrooklyn.com/blog/kombucha-mold-need-know/. Whether any of that is valid for vinegar, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, it does look like this is a duplicate question.  Thank you.